# Best way to DateDIFF Year based upon Month and DAY in SQL Microsoft Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out what is the best and accurate possible  way to calculate the difference between Years using MONTH and DAY. My attempt to this solution is: -

[CODE]CEILING(DATEDIFF(YEAR,DATE1,DATE2))[/CODE]

I want it to count 1.2 years, and round it up to 2 in final result, but it doesn't do that.

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server, yet you have tagged the question MySQL.  What database are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the title is descriptive of the actual problem or question. *SQL* is apparent in your tags, and *DateDiff* alone is not informative. Your question title should be descriptive and meaningful enough that it's useful to future readers who find it in a search result. While you're at it, you can clarify which DBMS you're using, as your syntax and your tag do not agree. MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: DATEDIFF only returns full integer results. If you want partial years, you need to get precision to the month or week and make an adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps doing the difference in months will be sufficient:

```
CEILING(DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATE1, DATE2) / 12.0) as Total
```

Note:  this requires about a 13 month difference to be considered two years.

Comment: Yes it is SQL server